# How do I lowercase any string and then capitalize only the first letter of the word with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm not sure if I did this right, as I am pretty new to JavaScript.

But I want to lowercase any random string text and then capitalize the first letter of each word in that text.

```html
<script>
    function capitalizeFirstLetter(string) {
        return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
    }

    function lowerCase(string) {
        return string.toLowerCase();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Did you find any error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A small sample:

```
function firstLetter(s) {

  return s.replace(/^.{1}/g, s[0].toUpperCase());
}

firstLetter('hello'); // Hello
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. will fail for mixed cases or all uppercase.

Comment: I think this also work `string.replace(/^\w/, c => c.toUpperCase())`

Answer (score 22):

Just change the method to

```
function capitalizeFirstLetter(string) 
{
  return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1).toLowerCase();
}
```

`.toLowerCase()` is appended to the last method call.

This method will make the first character uppercase and convert rest of the string to lowercase. You won't need the second method.

Comment: @dancemc15 your question says `But I want to lowercase any random string text and then capitalize the first letter of each word in that text.` But the answer you have accepted is only making the first letter capital. It is not making the rest of the string in lowercase.

Comment: function ucFirst(string) {
        if (!string || typeof string !== 'string') return '';
        return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1).toLowerCase();
    }